# Aligning two parts of a statement within an enumerate block

Tags: lists, align, enumerate

```
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Simplify the following symbolic statements
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item $(\pi > 0) \wedge (\pi < 10)$ & [Answer: $0 < \pi < 10$]
    \item $(p \geq 7) \wedge (p < 12)$ & [Answer: $7 \leq p < 12$]
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Some more text
  \item blah, blah.
\end{enumerate}
```

I have the following code above that results in an image like this
[image]

However, I want to align the left and right brackets in "[Answer:". How would I go about accomplishing this?

---

As a small sidenote, is it just me or does the editor not support rendering LaTeX via mathjax like math.stackexchange does?

Comment: So you want to align left *and* right brackets?

Comment: re sidenote: no, the tex.sx forum does *not* support rendering with mathjax.  the participants here need to see the input code, and mathjax subverts that.  see the meta question [Why doesn't maths render as maths?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1272/579) for more details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a box like

```
\item \makebox[0.5\textwidth][l]{$(p \geq 7) \wedge (p < 12)$}  [Answer: $7 \leq p < 12$]   Adjsut 0.5\textwidth
```

or use a `\hfill` like

```
\item $(\pi > 0) \wedge (\pi < 10)$ \hfill  [Answer: $0 < \pi < 10$]
```

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\begin{document}
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Simplify the following symbolic statements
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item \makebox[0.5\textwidth][l]{$(\pi > 0) \wedge (\pi < 10)$}  [Answer: $0 < \pi < 10$]
    \item \makebox[0.5\textwidth][l]{$(p \geq 7) \wedge (p < 12)$}  [Answer: $7 \leq p < 12$]
  \end{enumerate}
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item $(\pi > 0) \wedge (\pi < 10)$ \hfill  [Answer: $0 < \pi < 10$]
    \item $(p \geq 7) \wedge (p < 12)$ \hfill  [Answer: $7 \leq p < 12$]
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Some more text
  \item blah, blah.
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\documentclass{Article}`?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina That is a FCE (Frequently Committed Error) by me. :-) Thanks and corrected.

Answer (score 2):

I would take a slightly different approach from @harishkumar .  Namely, I would make the box for the answer and not the preceding material.  Also, you said you wanted both the left and right brackets to be aligned; this approach accomplishes that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}

\newcommand\answerbox[2][1.25in]{\hspace*{\fill}[\makebox[#1]{#2}]}

\begin{document}

\begin{enumerate}
  \item Simplify the following symbolic statements
  \begin{enumerate}[(a)]
    \item $(\pi > 0) \wedge (\pi < 10)$  \answerbox{Answer: $0 < \pi < 10$}
    \item $(p \geq 7) \wedge (p < 12)$   \answerbox{Answer: $7 \leq p < 12$}
  \end{enumerate}
  \item Some more text
  \item blah, blah.
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]